# Is there away of using ftell() with arduino?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-c++

This c code I use it to compute the number of values in the file:

```
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
  size_t inSize = ftell(file);
  size_t no_ofelem = inSize/2;
```

I converted it to work on Arduino ide in this way:

```
file.seek(file.size()); 
  inSize = file.position();  
  no_ofelem = inSize/2;
```

But this gave me different results –
`no_ofelem` in C is `2502`, in Arduino is `10`

Can you please tell me how can I use like `ftell(file);` with Arduino IDE ?

Comment: What results did you get? Wouldn't `no_ofelem = file.size()/2;` tell you the # of elements?

Comment: Yes, in c, no_ofelem = 2502. in arduino = 10. I'm using int16.

Comment: What file was that? I don't get why `file.size()` doesn't give you.

Comment: Aside: Why `int16`? Can the size be negative? Is it always going to be less that 32768?

Comment: I'm guessing they mean that the data stored in the file is `int16` values, and they're just explaining why they divide the file size by 2. But it's a fair point to ask for clarification, since they have not actually shown the types of `inSize` and `no_ofelem` in the second code example.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the types of the variables in the Arduino example. How are you determining the values? Using a debugger? Are you printing them / logging them on a UART or something? Please show that code too, if it exists.

Comment: Please show a [mre]. Also: What _is_ `file.size()` returning (before you divide or assign it to a variable we know nothing about)?

Comment: What platform is this? What is `file` in both cases?

Comment: I update my qyestion, Could you check it please?

Comment: @stella you need to crack open a book and find out about passing the address of a variable to a function. In both versions, the variables dealing with number of elements are an absolute muddle. It would do no good to provide you with corrected code. You need to master this basic concept (and correct your own code) or else you be unable to progress in your learning. SO is not intended as a tutoring site.

Comment: Note that `pFile.size();` returns an `unsigned long` and `%d` is not the correct conversion specifier for an `unsigned long` (if `Serial.printf` is anything like the standard `printf`). Use `%lu` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to follow the `ftell` way.

`file.size()` gives you the file size and you do not need to do anything else.

So if your file contains binary representation of the `int16_t` or `uint16_t`

you need to

```
unsigned long no_ofelem = file.size() / sizeof(uint16_t)
```